# Facebook graph API insights results change depending on time of call

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I would appreciate if someone could explain the following behavior of Facebook Insights:
I query the page_fans metric using the graph api on an hourly basis. As can be seen in the image below, the results are constant, then at midnight (UTC) there is a sudden jump which stays pretty consistent until 7am UTC (midnight on the West Coast), when it goes back down to the normal consistent level.This behavior repeats every night. It seems that during these hours the data is some kind of prediction and not actual.
What is going on??

[image: Sample responses over time]

Answer (score 0):

Insight metrics numbers are generally subject to change. But you generally get relatively stable numbers when querying after 7 days. You will see that the metrics numbers stay stable after that.